# What workout routine is best for a 14 year old?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle, strength, workout, muscle-gain

I'm a skinny 14 year old weighing about 50 kg, and I need to find a good workout routine (doesn't matter how long). I'm looking for a workout that targets my biceps, triceps and core. Can you suggest any good workout routine, and possibly diet as I need I'm extremely skinny?

Thanks!

Comment: What about legs? Are you only after trophy muscles, or do you want an overall program? Do you do any sports? Plan to?

Comment: To be honest, for now, I feel I need to concentrate on my core, abs, biceps and triceps. As for sports, I play basketball and football quite a bit and go running at least once a week. (swimming occasionally)

Comment: What sort of fitness goals do you have? What is your PRIMARY concern? Do you mainly want to get bigger muscles (bodybuilding)? Do you mainly want to get stronger (Powerlifting/Strongman)? Do you mainly want to be explosive and have more stamina (athletic training)? Is there a specific sport you want to improve in? Is there another primary concern entirely? Knowing this is critical to offering an appropriate answer.

Comment: For now I'm just focusing on increasing muscle mass.

Comment: As a beginner and a young guy, almost any consistent lifting combined with a good diet will provide results... emphasis on "consistent" and "good diet". To get started watch some Youtube videos and pick and choose the things you enjoy. personal recommendation: BUFF Dudes

Answer (score 1):

Weight training is safe for growing children so if you want to do weightlifting, any free program would do.

If you are more into bodyweight stuff I'd suggests joining a gymanstics gym.